# Python and the new way to add data to urllib requests

Tags: python, urllib, python-3.4

I'm getting the error,

`AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'add_data'`

from a library that uses urllib.request

[In Python 2.7-3.3 urllib.request contained a `add_data()` method.](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.add_data)

But In Python 3.4 the documentation states that,

[Changed in version 3.4: The request methods add_data, has_data, get_data, get_type, get_host, get_selector, get_origin_req_host and is_unverifiable that were deprecated since 3.3 have been removed.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.add_data)

How do I add data to urllib requests in Python3.4?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Just assign to the `data` attribute for `urllib.request`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.data)

```
 request.data = "Some data"
```